# SQL Update hangs Java program

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm writing a combination Java/Perl program that parses XML files into an Oracle SQL database. There are two tables in the database - one that holds the data from the XML files and another that holds information about the files themselves (file name, creation time, etc.). Basically, when a new XML file comes along, the Java program checks to see if it has already been parsed, or partially parsed. If it has, it changes the `STATUS` column in the filestatus table from 'good' to 'bad' for that file ID, using `UPDATE FILESTATUS SET STATUS='bad' WHERE ID=?`. However, when I run it, it gets stuck doing this. Any ideas why this could happen? No error messages are occurring, it just hangs. The code is below.

```
static void markDataBad(String docID)
    {
        try
        {
            String update = "UPDATE FILESTATUS SET STATUS='bad' WHERE ID=?";
            PreparedStatement updateStatus = Main.con.prepareStatement(update);
            updateStatus.setString(1, docID);
            updateStatus.execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

I've already tried changing `updateStatus.execute()` to `updateStatus.executeQuery()` and `updateStatus.executeUpdate()`, but nothing seems to have changed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have uncommited changes to that table somewhere else?  I had this problem today because I'd made some changes to the table in SQL*Developer, and that was holding onto a lock on the table until I committed it.

Comment: Turns out I did. Ran commit on the database and now it updates without a problem (well, except for the problems that came up further along in the code).

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Was experimenting in SQL-developer meanwhile, solved it by closing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your user have permission for that table?
Have you issued before a lock on the table or a missing commit?
Can you run the query in shell?