# Cannot update Oracle view from JDBC

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, lotus-domino

Overview:   Need to read row from Oracle view and create a Notes document, save document, then write Document Unique ID back to Oracle.

I am able to read connect and read data no problem.   I am using a type 4 connection connecting to an Oracle 11 database.  The Oracle view is setup to allow Updating.  The view has nothing in it that is outline here: [In Oracle, is it possible to INSERT or UPDATE a record through a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652995/in-oracle-is-it-possible-to-insert-or-update-a-record-through-a-view)

*With the same username and password, you are able to successfully update view by typing in SQL statement.

*Tried using conn.setAutoCommit(false);  This had no effect.

*Verified that the result set was updatable (1008)

*User has been given full DBA access (temporarily)

*I have tried every possible combination of the first parameter in the createStatement method

```
...
Statement statement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(fetch);
...
String UNID = doc.getUniversalID(); //gets unique id from saved Notes Document  
System.out.println("This is what to write to Oracle:" + UNID);
System.out.println("is updatable=1008, not updatable=1007 value is:" + rs.getConcurrency());
System.out.println("is Result Set Closed:" + rs.isClosed());

rs.updateString("NOTES_DOC_ID", UNID);
System.out.println("got past updating NOTES_DOC_ID column");
rs.updateRow();  //fails here
```

> Here is the error from console:
>
> > This is what to write to Oracle:BF8091259610C61B87257B16005C14FB
> >
> > is updatable=1008, not updatable=1007 value is:1008
> >
> > is Result Set Closed:false
> >
> > got past updating NOTES_DOC_ID column
> >
> > java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM.0)

Prior to asking for the user to have DBA access I would get a

> > java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

I think this a big clue.  My DBA doesn't know what further access to give me.

The DBA is wanting me to start using ref cursors, which is fine, but I suspect there is some kind of security setting for JDBC access that is tripping me up, and I want to explore that first.  If there is a security issue, then I don't think changing the way I read the rows is going to make a difference.  Most of all the documentation on how to do this was obtained from Oracle's website, as well as this site.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a "plain" UPDATE statement? I never saw updateable resultsets work properly in any database.

Comment: Not really an option as this point due to nature of the data.  Cursors need to be used.

Comment: If you try to update the view directly in sql, say with sql*plus, does it work? IMHO, giving DBA rights is not the brightest idea ever.

Comment: I didn't do it personally, but the DBA said he could update using TOra.  It seems to fail only from JDBC.   We tried yesterday creating an access control list, and allowing all access from my ip address, but that did nothing.  The DBA access is only temporary and was just done to rule out an user access issue.

Comment: Question:  The DBA renamed the default port 1521 to something else, could that cause an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my question and explain how I got past this roadblock.  In the end, I basically did what 'a_horse_with_no_name' suggested.

Instead of using the resultSet cursor or a ref cursor to perform the update, I was able to use a plain UPDATE statement.   This was possible, because I was able to convince the DBA to create a column for a unique identifier.  We could never get around the exceptions caused by the updateRow() method of the resultSet.  Prior to him adding the unique identifier, there was not a key in which to reliably use the UPDATE statement.

Here is the code where updateSQL is a string holding the update SQL statement:

```
updateResultInt = updateStatement.executeUpdate(updateSQL);
```

It returns a 1 if successful.

One word of caution, if you are using a tools like TOra or sql plus to check your update statements, you have to remember to manually commit them.  If you don't your java agent will hang when trying to run it.  Here is an good reference that helped me with that issue:  [SQL Update hangs Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276283/sql-update-hangs-java-program)

Thanks to those who commented!